# How do i prove existence of a subgroup of order $p^n$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I'm trying to prove this by induction.

Let $G$ be a finite group and $p$ be a prime.

Assume that $p^{n+1}$ divides $|G|$.

Let $H$ be a subgroup of $G$ such that $|H|=p^n$.

Since $|G:H|=|N_G(H)/H|$, by Cauchy's theorem, there exists a subgroup $K$ of $N_G(H)/H$ such that $|K|=p$.

Let $\phi:N_G(H)\rightarrow N_G(H)/H$ be the natural homomorphism.

Define $A=\phi^{-1}(K)$

I have proven that $H<A\leq N_G(H)$.

In my text, it's written there $|A|=p^{n+1}$, but i don't have any clue why..

How so??

Comment: $A/H \cong K$ has order $p$ and $|H| = p^{n}.$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The subgroup $K$ of the quotient $N_G(H)/H$ has $p$ elements, those elements are $H$-cosets (each having $p^n$ elements), and $A=\phi^{-1}(K)$ is just *their union*.